# Custom MessageBox using Window

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, messagebox, showdialog

In regard to the code below.

If I use the built in MessageBox, then the previous MessageBox has to be closed before the next one is displayed.

How can I achieve this with a Window so that I can create a custom message box? I tried using the ShowDialog method, but whilst this does create Modal windows, it still shows them all at the same time cascaded.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowDialog2()));
        }
    }

    void ShowDialog2()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("A message");

        Window w = new Window() { Width = 200, Height = 200, Content = "SomeText" };
        w.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open first instance of window with `ShowDialog` and consequent instances of window with `Show` method.

**Show open a non-modal window whereas ShowDialog open modal window.**

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain too well, but I want the user to only be able to see one of the customs windows at a time, so forcing them to close the previous one before the next one is displayed.

Comment: That seems not intuitive. How exactly you want user to be notified about that?

Comment: If you run the example you'll see what I mean. The result using MessageBox behaves differenly to the approach using Windows. When using MessageBoxes you see one after the other only after the previous one has closed (this is what I want). When using custom Windows you see them all at the same time (not what I want, I only want to see the next window after the previous is closed, which is what the MessageBox seems to do)